# how to pass params to link_to root_url when using subdomain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, subdomain, link-to

I am trying to get the link to go to

```
admin.mysite.com/articles/new
```

and currently am using

```
link_to 'new article', [root_url(subdomain: 'admin), 'articles/new'].join
```

but am sure there's  a better (rails) way to do it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the URL helper with subdomain as below:

```
link_to 'new article', new_article_url(subdomain: 'admin')
```

Assuming `new_article_url` will points to `articles/new`.